# How to add background color only to scroll the menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this page:

[link](http://dg-design.ch/bagel/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="content-menu">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse bs-docs-nav" role="banner" id="menu-top">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                         //some code html
                       </div>
                   </div>    
</div>
```

the top menu id want to add to scroll CSS class which is presented below

**CODE CSS:**

```
.bg-scroll{
  background: red;
}
```

I tried to use the JS code below

**CODE JS:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#menu-top").addClass("bg-scroll");
});
```

Can you tell me please what is wrong?code is quite simple ... the scroll function works smoothly but do not add the respective class

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have JS errors on your page. This will probably stop the JS from working elsewhere.

Comment: try this `background: red !important;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have should work, you probably just have an issue with css selector specificity.

ID based CSS selectors like `#menu-top` have a higher precedence than Class based CSS selectors like `.bg-scroll`

Try making your CSS selector for `.bg-scroll` more specific:

```
#menu-top.bg-scroll { background: red; }
```

Or to be more reusable:

```
.navbar.bg-scroll { background: red; }
```

Using `!important` will also work but is generally considered a bad practice because it can make debugging more difficult:

```
.bg-scroll { background: red !important; }
```

Read more about best practices: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity